# Python_Selecting longest AA sequence

Tags: python

I have the following sequences and I am trying to select the longest sequence. I know that it is the First sequence, but how do I tell Python to select the sequence with the longest distance between M (start) and * (stop)?

```
First= MATVEPETTPTPNPPTTEEEKTESNQEVANPEHYIKHPLQNRWALWFFKNDKSKTWQANLRLISKFDTVEDFWALYNHIQLSSNLMPGCDYSLFKDGIEPMWEDEKNKRGGRWLITLNKQQRRSDLDRFWLETLLCLIGESFDDYSDDVCGAVVNVRAKGDKIAIWTTECENREAVTHIGRVYKERLGLPPKIVIGYQSHADTATKSGSTTKNRFVV*    
Second= WRLSNRKPPLLLIPRLQKRRKRNLIRRLLTQNTILNIPYRTDGHSGFLKMIKAKLGKQTCG*SPSLILLKTFGLCTTISSCLVI*CLAVTTHFLRMVLSLCGKMRKTNGEDDG*LH*TNSRDEVTSIAFG*RHFCALLENLLMTTVMMYVALLLMLELKVIR*QYGLLNVKTEKLLHI*GGYTRKG*DFLQR**LVISPTQTQLLRAAPPLKIGLLF    
Third= GDCRTGNHPYS*SPDYRRGENGI*SGGC*PRTLY*TSPTEQMGTLVF*K**KQNLASKPAADLQV*YC*RLLGSVQPYPVV**FNAWL*LLTF*GWY*AYVGR*EKQTGRTMANYIEQTAETK*PRSLLARDTSVPYWRIF**LQ**CMWRCC*C*S*R**DSNMDY*M*KQRSCYTYREGIQGKVRTSSKDSDWLSVPRRHSY*ERLHH*K*VCCL    
Fourth= LNNKPIFSGGAALSSCVCVGLITNHYLWRKS*PFLVYPPYMCNSFSVFTFSSPYCYLITFSSNINNSATYIITVVIKRFSNKAQKCL*PKAIEVTSSLLFVQCN*PSSSPFVFLIFPHRLNTILKK*VVTARH*ITRQLDMVVQSPKVFNSIKLGDQPQVCLPSFAFIIFKKPECPSVL*GMFNIVFWVSNLLIRFRFLLFCSRGIRSRGGFRFDSRH    
Fifth= *TTNLFLVVEPLLVAVSAWD**PITIFGGSPNLSLYTLPICVTASLFSHSVVHIAILSPLALTLTTAPHTSSL*SSKDSPIRHRSVSSQKRSRSLRLCCLFNVISHRPPRLFFSSSHIGSIPSLKSE*SQPGIKLLDNWIWLYRAQKSSTVSNLEISRRFACQVLLLSFLKNQSAHLFCRGCLI*CSGLATS*LDSVFSSSVVGGLGVGVVSGSTVA    
Sixth= KQQTYF*WWSRS**LCLRGTDNQSLSLEEVLTFPCIPSLYV*QLLCFHIQ*SILLSYHL*L*H*QQRHIHHHCSHQKILQ*GTEVSLAKSDRGHFVSAVCSM*LAIVLPVCFSHLPT*AQYHP*KVSSHSQALNY*TTGYGCTEPKSLQQYQTWRSAAGLLAKFCFYHF*KTRVPICSVGDV*YSVLG*QPPD*IPFSPLL*SGD*E*GWFPVRQSP
```

Answer (score 1):

To get you started, here's a few basic commands to get the lengths you're interested in. I defined a function that checks the length between the first elements found of each character.

```
First= 'MATVEPETTPTPNPPTTEEEKTESNQEVANPEHYIKHPLQNRWALWFFKNDKSKTWQANLRLISKFDTVEDFWALYNHIQLSSNLMPGCDYSLFKDGIEPMWEDEKNKRGGRWLITLNKQQRRSDLDRFWLETLLCLIGESFDDYSDDVCGAVVNVRAKGDKIAIWTTECENREAVTHIGRVYKERLGLPPKIVIGYQSHADTATKSGSTTKNRFVV*'
Second= 'WRLSNRKPPLLLIPRLQKRRKRNLIRRLLTQNTILNIPYRTDGHSGFLKMIKAKLGKQTCGSPSLILLKTFGLCTTISSCLVICLAVTTHFLRMVLSLCGKMRKTNGEDDGLHTNSRDEVTSIAFGRHFCALLENLLMTTVMMYVALLLMLELKVIRQYGLLNVKTEKLLHIGGYTRKGDFLQR**LVISPTQTQLLRAAPPLKIGLLF'
Third= 'GDCRTGNHPYSSPDYRRGENGISGGCPRTLYTSPTEQMGTLVFKKQNLASKPAADLQVYCRLLGSVQPYPVVFNAWLLLTFGWYAYVGREKQTGRTMANYIEQTAETKPRSLLARDTSVPYWRIFLQCMWRCCCS*R**DSNMDYMKQRSCYTYREGIQGKVRTSSKDSDWLSVPRRHSYERLHHK*VCCL'
Fourth= 'LNNKPIFSGGAALSSCVCVGLITNHYLWRKSPFLVYPPYMCNSFSVFTFSSPYCYLITFSSNINNSATYIITVVIKRFSNKAQKCLPKAIEVTSSLLFVQCNPSSSPFVFLIFPHRLNTILKKVVTARHITRQLDMVVQSPKVFNSIKLGDQPQVCLPSFAFIIFKKPECPSVLGMFNIVFWVSNLLIRFRFLLFCSRGIRSRGGFRFDSRH'
Fifth= '*TTNLFLVVEPLLVAVSAWD**PITIFGGSPNLSLYTLPICVTASLFSHSVVHIAILSPLALTLTTAPHTSSLSSKDSPIRHRSVSSQKRSRSLRLCCLFNVISHRPPRLFFSSSHIGSIPSLKSESQPGIKLLDNWIWLYRAQKSSTVSNLEISRRFACQVLLLSFLKNQSAHLFCRGCLICSGLATSLDSVFSSSVVGGLGVGVVSGSTVA'
Sixth= 'KQQTYF*WWSRS**LCLRGTDNQSLSLEEVLTFPCIPSLYVQLLCFHIQSILLSYHLLHQQRHIHHHCSHQKILQGTEVSLAKSDRGHFVSAVCSMLAIVLPVCFSHLPTAQYHPKVSSHSQALNYTTGYGCTEPKSLQQYQTWRSAAGLLAKFCFYHFKTRVPICSVGDVYSVLGQPPDIPFSPLLSGDE*GWFPVRQSP'

def sequence_length( string, char1, char2 ):
    try:
        return string.index(char2) - string.index(char1)
    except ValueError:
        return None

print( sequence_length( First, 'M', '*' ) )
print( sequence_length( Second, 'M', '*' ) )
print( sequence_length( Third, 'M', '*' ) )
print( sequence_length( Fourth, 'M', '*' ) )
print( sequence_length( Fifth, 'M', '*' ) )
print( sequence_length( Sixth, 'M', '*' ) )
```

returns this:

```
217
135
98
None
None
-89
```